# CW-structure induced by Morse function on Riemannian manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, morse-theory

I have heard a statement in the following direction. Given a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ with a Morse function on it possibly satisfying some extra assumptions. Then this data induces a CW-structure on $M$: to each critical point corresponds a cell - its unstable submanifold. The main difficulty is to construct a compactification of these cells.

> I am looking for a reference to a precise statement of the result, possibly with some details of the construction.

At the moment I am less interested in a detailed proof.

Comment: This is answered in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11375/cw-structures-and-morse-functions-a-reference-request, see in particular, Hatcher's answer. Voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: Thanks for that reference: I have posted my answer there and also voted to close this question.

Answer (score 3):

I have not read it (It is on my ever-growing todo list), but the paper

```
Qin, Lizhen(1-WYNS)
On moduli spaces and CW structures arising from Morse theory on Hilbert manifolds.
J. Topol. Anal. 2 (2010), no. 4, 469–526.
58E05 (37D15 57R19)
```

should contain the proofs of what you want. From the Mathscinet review of D. Hurtubise

> This paper contains precise statements and careful proofs of several
>   essential results that are fundamental to the moduli space approach to
>   Morse theory. Most of the results in this paper have appeared and/or
>   been used in other papers, but this is the first self-contained
>   reference that provides clear and complete proofs of all of the
>   following: (1) the smooth structures on the compactified spaces that
>   arise from the gradient flow of a Morse-Smale function, (2)
>   orientation formulas for the strata of the compactified spaces, and
>   (3) the CW structure determined by the unstable manifolds of a
>   Morse-Smale function. The results are proved for a Morse function on a
>   complete Hilbert manifold that satisfies the Palais-Smale Condition
>   (C) and has finite index at each critical point (the CF case).

Of course this also proves the CW structure in the finite dimensional case.